# Setting a fix width of combobox and textbox in java

Tags: java, swing

I have a combo box and on the right side of it in teh same panel I have four more buttons. On teh south part of the panel I have one more button, and the click action on it results in hiding the four buttons on the right of the combo. As a result combo widens. I want to add one label and one text box on the right side of it, instead of the four buttons that are hidden in this case. But since the combo box widened, the space on the right is not enough for the text box and the label. In fact I can see the whole label box, but the text box is very narrow, hardly visible.

I would like to ask you kindly to help me how to set the fix width of the combo, and the text box I added?

This is the code I have now:

```
    pPaint = new JPanel();


    GridBagLayout pPaintLayout = new GridBagLayout();
    pPaintLayout.columnWidths = new int[] {7, 7, 7, 7, 7};
    pPaintLayout.rowHeights = new int[] {25};
    pPaintLayout.columnWeights = new double[] {100.0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1};
    pPaintLayout.rowWeights = new double[] {0.1};
    pPaint.setLayout(pPaintLayout);

    {
        cobSections = new JComboBox();
        cobSections.setRenderer(new    MapSectionItemRenderer());
        pPaint.add(cobSections, new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0,
        GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,
        new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
        cobSections.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        cobSectionsActionPerformed(evt);
    }
      });
      }
          {
            lTimeInterval = new JLabel("interval");
            lTimeInterval.setVisible(false);
            pPaint.add(lTimeInterval, new GridBagConstraints(1, 0, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0,
            GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE,
            new Insets(0, 5, 0, 0), 0, 0));
            }
          {

                tfInputTinter = new JTextField();
                tfInputTinter.setVisible(false);
                pPaint.add(tfInputTinter, new GridBagConstraints(2, 0, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0,
                        GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE,
                        new Insets(0, 5, 0, 0), 0, 0));
            }
```

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: I solved the problem with tfInputTinter = new JTextField(10);